# Microsoft Graph Sites and Lists API - adding new hidden column is visible in default view

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, sharepoint-list

We are adding a new hidden columns in the Default Document list using [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0) , following is the payload

```
{

            "description": "Test column for testing hidden",
            "displayName": "Test_DCR_3",
            "hidden": true,
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "Test_DCR_3",
            "required": false,
            "text": {
            }
        }
```

As per the documentation the column should be hidden from the UI but its visible in the default view of the list as shown below.

[image]

This looks like an issue in the current implementation of adding column using graph api.

This is a show stopper for us as we don't want to confuse end users with showing hidden columns, if there is a work around to get it working please let me know.